# MyBatis Multiple Resultset with annotation alone

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, mybatis

As the title suggests I am trying to map multiple result sets with annotations alone heres my scenario.

`Proc_A` returns 3 result sets for these models

```
org.example.models.ModelA = as Single Result
org.example.models.ModelB = as List<>
org.example.models.ModelC = as List<>
```

I know you can do a XML & @Annotation Method like so.

```
//ExampleMapper.java
public interface ExampleMapper {
  @Select("EXEC Proc_A #{userID}")
  @ResultMap("getModelA","getModelB","getModelC")
  @Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
  List<List<?>> executeProcA(@Param("userID") Integer userID)
}
```

And Xml

```
//ExampleMapper.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace="org.example.mybatis.ExampleMapper" >
    <!-- Result Maps for Proc_A -->
    <resultMap id="getModelA" type="org.example.models.ModelA" />
    <resultMap id="getModelB" type="org.example.models.ModelB" />
    <resultMap id="getModelC" type="org.example.models.ModelC" />
</mapper>
```

**This works fine in most cases however I would like to know is there a way to do this with only Annotations**

*Update*

I found `@Results` and `@Result` however `@Results` documentation imlpies it is for one result set. However I did notice in `@Result` a one and many indicators have yet to find documentation on their use to see if they will help.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: @jamesj Unfortunately I have not yet, I have worked around it using the XML and annotation method and checking Mybatis site for any information.